# upload to play store 64 bit

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying upload an app to the google play store, i got an error that say my app does not surpport 64 bit machines and there was link to help [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit).

i followed all the instructions to add

> **ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'**

but am still getting this error. is there a way i can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this blog to understand the new apk upload issues in playstore it is mandatory if you are using any native to support 64 bit devices, so you need to add little bit code in gradle file and need to add the native files to support 64 bit devices,

Please follow this developers blog https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit